# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Unsure of why this is happening?? Still a noob..

I am just updating one field in the `Mine` table before I save the record. All of the variables are being pulled in accurately.. The below line returns what its supposed too.

```
CreateFulfillmentService::NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?(self.marketplace)
```

And `self` is an instance of `Mine`. And `self.marketplace` returns the correct marketplace.

This is my controller

```
class Mine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  validates :merchant_id, presence: true
  validates :auth_token, presence: true
  before_save :assign_three_speed

def assign_three_speed
  if CreateFulfillmentService::NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?(self.marketplace)
    self.update(three_speed: false)
  else
    self.update(three_speed: true)     
  end
end

end
```

Where did I go astray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`before_save` is a callback. It runs every time you save an instance of Mine.

In `assign_three_speed`, you call `self.update`, which ends up up calling `save`. That save call triggers another callback cycle, and the loop continues forever (until it quits with the SystemStackError).

Try assigning three_speed in the callback instead (instead of updating). The change will persist to the database because the assignment occurs *before* the model is saved.

```
def assign_three_speed
  if CreateFulfillmentService::NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?(self.marketplace)
    self.three_speed = false
  else
    self.three_speed = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it.. I'll accept the answer in a minute.. won't let me right now